# Select multiple cardview and remove the position on unselect in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veq4A.png)Hello there! i am working on recyclerview in android. in recyclerview i am selecting multiple cardview. But i want when i select cardviews then their position should be concatenated 
as 1,2,3,4,5 
and when i unselect the cardview then their postions should be removed. Suppose I unselect the cardview at position 5 then concatenated string will be 
1,2,3,4
like this
here is my adapter code:

```
if (!brand.isSelected()) {
    brand.setSelected(!brand.isSelected());
    name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    Log.e("boolean",String.valueOf(!brand.isSelected()));
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fe8d00"));
} else {
    brand.setSelected(!brand.isSelected());
    name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}

if (brands.get(position).isSelected()) {
    String selecName = brand.getBrandName();
    finalName = selecName + " " + finalName;
    Toast.makeText(context,finalName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and here is my model:

```
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}
public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}
```

and here is image of selecting the cardview

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103578/7666442

Comment: my code is same like this but how i can remove unselected name from previous concatenated string

Comment: How about adding a list of ints containing the position values you have selected.
If you deselect just remove from list.
also you can join the elements to String