# How to add checked items to my arraylist?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

Hi I am using recyclerview with checkbox, now what I am trying is whatever list items user checks, I want to add that items in my arraylist, right now it is not working and it adds all the listitems instead of adding checked ones. following is my code of adapter.can  any one help me to solve this?

```
public static class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public static ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList;
        private Context ctx;


        public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList) {

            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            this.imageModelArrayList = imageModelArrayList;
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.checkBox.setText("Checkbox " + position);
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getSelected());
            holder.tvAnimal.setText(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getAnimal());
            alertviewlist =new ArrayList<ArrayList<Model>>();
            // holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
            holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Integer pos = (Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getAnimal() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //alertviewlist.addAll(imageModelArrayList);
                    for (int i = 0; i < imageModelArrayList.size(); i++) {
                        alertviewlist.add(i, imageModelArrayList);
                    }
                    System.out.println(alertviewlist.size());
                    if (imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                        imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                    } else {
                        imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return imageModelArrayList.size();
        }

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected CheckBox checkBox;
            private TextView tvAnimal;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
                tvAnimal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103578/7666442

Comment: in your model, keep a boolean variable to know whether that item is checked or not and add that to your arraylist only if it is checked

Comment: @NileshRathod i want to add selected names in my new arrraylist, please check question carefully

Comment: @VivekMishra see the toast, as soon as user check i am getting animal names, i want to add checked ones in my alertviewlist

Comment: @khimjiI have checked the question carefully you need to check the linked answer carefully using that answer u will get the hint, and please be nice with community no one is here to write code for you we all are here to each other

Comment: You are on the right track but you don't need for loop to add checked item to the list.Just like you are showing your toast, add that particular element in your checked list

Comment: @NileshRathod whatever items user will check, i want to create another arraylist and that arraylist i want to use for another recyclerview, that is what i am trying

Comment: @VivekMishra then it is giving error and force to convert my arraylist to string

Comment: your alertViewList declaration is wrong. It should be same as your imageModelArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you want to make your `alertViewList` as a list of list item? This is your `alertviewlist`:

```
alertviewlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Model>>();
```

Based on your description, i think what you want to make is a list that store the models right? Then it should be:

```
alertviewlist = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

And for storing the model, you don't need add the list of `imageModelArrayList` into `alertviewlist`. You only need to add a single model from your `imageModelArrayList` with the given `pos` into your `alertviewlist`. Here i change the code of your `checkBox.setOnClickListener` :

```
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer pos = (Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getAnimal() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //store your model into alertviewlist
                alertviewlist.add(imageModelArrayList.get(pos))

                System.out.println(alertviewlist.size());
                if (imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                    imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: is it possible can i create one more arraylist of Uri, like this ?

Comment: It should be fine, as long as you hold the position of item that you want to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

In **CustomAdapter** class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
public static ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList;
private Context ctx;


public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Model> imageModelArrayList) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.imageModelArrayList = imageModelArrayList;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Model dResult = imageModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(dResult.getSelected());
    holder.checkBox.setTag(dResult);

    if (dResult.isSelected()) {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.checkBox.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.checkBox.setSelected(false);
    }

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                holder.checkBox.setSelected(true);
                dResult.setSelected(true);
            }else {
                holder.checkBox.setSelected(false);
                dResult.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageModelArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView tvAnimal;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        tvAnimal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal);
    }
}}
```

Then In your activity class get **selected item** into arraylist.

`ArrayList<String> SelectedList = new ArrayList<String>();`

```
for (int i=0;i<imageModelArrayList.size;i++){
        if (imageModelArrayList.get(i).getSelected()==true){
            SelectedList.add(imageModelArrayList.get(i).getAnimal());
        }
}
```

Then you can get selected animal name into list.