# How to restore checkBox state in Android RecyclerView list items on Rotation of device

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox, android-viewmodel

My current Android application contains a RecyclerView that has a checkBox present in each item within the list.

My issue is that on screen rotation the checkbox always returns to the unchecked state.

I am storing my updated list items within my activities ViewModel and pass this saved list back to the adapter in onCreate

From my debug logs I can see the list state correctly holds the checked/unchecked state of each list item.

I have also logged out the list in the adapter constructor that also shows the checked state is still valid.

however when `onBindViewHolder` is called the list items are all unchecked.

**here are my code snippets:-**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        manageViewModel();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_rv);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        adapter = new MedicationAdapter(viewModel.getList(), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }



protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    viewModel.saveList(adapter.getList());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
```

**My list item checkBox is defined as follows in xml:-**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/my_checkbox_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="" />
```

What is the correct approach to keeping checkbox state within a RecyclerView item(s) on device rotation?

**My adapter code:-**

```
    public class MusicalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private static final String TAG = "MusicalAdapter";
        private int previousExpandedPosition = -1;
        private int mExpandedPosition = -1;

        private final List<MusicalUI> musicals = new ArrayList<>();
        private final ItemClickListener clickListener;

        MusicalAdapter(final List<MusicalUI> musicals, final ItemClickListener clickListener) {
            this.musicals.clear();
            this.musicals.addAll(musicals);
//AT THIS POINT THE CHECKED VALUES ARE AS EXPECTED

            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MusicalAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_disco_item_x, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MusicalAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final MusicalUI musical = musicals.get(position);

            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder() called with: musical = [" + musical.getChecked());

// AT THI SPOINT THE CHECKED VALUES ARE ALWAYS FALSE!!!!!!!!
            final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;


            for (final MusicalUI musicalx : musicals) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder(): " + musicalx.getChecked());
            }

            // Header
            holder.discoDetailsHeaderLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.musicalNameHeader.setText(musical.getDiscoName());

            holder.discoSelectedHeader.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.discoSelectedHeader.setChecked(musical.getChecked());
            holder.discoSelectedHeader.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> musical.setChecked(isChecked));


            if (isExpanded)
                previousExpandedPosition = position;

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
                notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return musicals.size();
        }


        MusicalUI getItem(final int position) {
            return musicals.get(position);
        }

        void updateList(final List<MusicalUI> newMusicals) {
            final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new GenericDiffUtilCallback<>(this.musicals, newMusicals));
            diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);

            this.musicals.clear();
            this.musicals.addAll(newMusicals);
        }

        List<MusicalUI> getList() {
            return musicals;
        }

        /**
         *
         */
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    ...
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: check this my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103578/7666442 it will give you  a hint

Comment: @NileshRathod, my PoJo already has a Boolean field, this field is correctly set until I try to use it in onBindViewHolder and then its always false. Even though I created my recyclerView adapter with a valid "checked" list.

Comment: share your adapter code with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes because when rotation is changed, your activity restarts. You can either write a lot of code to restore your state **or** you can just avoid restart. This is correct way

**To make your activity not restart in rotation changes**

in AndroidManifest find your activity and add

`android:configChanges="orientation"`

Android also recommends to avoid it for most of the cases

It says let android handle config changes itself

> Caution: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much
>   more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does
>   not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be
>   considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a
>   configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.
>
> To declare that your activity handles a configuration change, edit the
>   appropriate  element in your manifest file to include the
>   android:configChanges attribute with a value that represents the
>   configuration you want to handle. Possible values are listed in the
>   documentation for the android:configChanges attribute. The most
>   commonly used values are "orientation", "screenSize", and
>   "keyboardHidden". The "orientation" value prevents restarts when the
>   screen orientation changes.

[More Info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)