# notifyDataSetChanged() in Adapter doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

There is a delete button in my `recyclerView`. When the button is clicked,user can delete it based on position. After that I would like the `recyclerView` to update. I have added below code in my adapter class but it still doesn't work.

```
 notifyItemRemoved(position)
 notifyDataSetChanged()
```

**Adapter**

```
 holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)

            // Set the alert dialog title
            builder.setTitle("Delete Item")

            // Display grid_item message on alert dialog
            builder.setMessage("Are you want to delete this item ?")

            // Display grid_item negative button on alert dialog
            builder.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, which ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            // Set grid_item positive button and its click listener on alert dialog
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, which ->

                var dialog = Util().callDialog(context)

                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

                    val service = RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService()
                    service.delete(item.id)
                }
                val handler = Handler()
                handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                    notifyItemRemoved(position)
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                    context.longToast("Done")
                }, 5000)
            }
            // Finally, make the alert dialog using builder
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

            // Display the alert dialog on app interface
            dialog.show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you are removing item from your list?

Comment: You need to remove item from data list also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not removing item from your list that's why `notifyItemRemoved(position)`
and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not working

Make below changes in your code

```
handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                    // remove here item from yourlist then use notifyItemRemoved(position)
                    arrayList.removeAt(position)
                    notifyItemRemoved(position)
                    //notifyDataSetChanged() // Is not necessary.
                    context.longToast("Done")
                }, 5000)
```

Comment: I need to use `removeAt` instead of `remove`

Comment: @JohnJoe didn't get u buddy

Comment: I get this `Using 'remove(Int): T' is an error. Use removeAt(index) instead`

Comment: hi bro, I have another button called `A` in the recyclerView. If `A` clicked, it will call some function, then I want A to be invisible.  How can I achieve ?

Comment: @JohnJoe than you need to  take a boolean variable for that and maintain  boolean  visibilty of button called `A` using that boolean varble, means when user click on button change the state of boolean variable and disply button based on that Boolean variable

Comment: @JohnJoe for hint check my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103578/7666442

Answer (score 2):

You must remove selected item from your list then notify adapter.

Please try this code:

```
yourDataset.removeAt(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, yourDataset.size()); //If needed
```

Hopefully this steps will help you removing items from a recycler view.