# Change the background color of selected item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background-color, selecteditem

I have a recyclerview where i want to change the color of the selected item and re change it on unselected. I have used an string arraylist and an interface for that here is interface code in adapter -

```
  public interface Callback{
        void onItemClicked(String i_name, boolean longClick);
    }
```

Here is onclick and onlongclick code-

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           String[] tag = ((String) view.getTag()).split(":");
           String i_name = tag[1];
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+i_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(callback != null)
        {
            callback.onItemClicked(i_name,false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        String[] tag = ((String) view.getTag()).split(":");
        String i_name = tag[1];
        if(callback != null)
        {
            callback.onItemClicked(i_name,false);
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Here is the toggleselected code -

```
  public void toggleSelected(String i_name)
    {
        final boolean newState = !selectedList.contains(i_name);
        if(newState)
        {
         // i want to give background color to i_name

               selectedList.add(i_name);
               Toast.makeText(context, "selected list1- "+selectedList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            selectedList.remove((String) i_name);
            Toast.makeText(context, "selected list2- "+selectedList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

here is onItemClicked code from fragment -

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClicked(String i_name, boolean longClick) {
        if(longClick)
        {
             ((MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter).toggleSelected(i_name);
        }
        else
        {
            ((MyCategoryAdaptercheckbox) MyAdapter).toggleSelected(i_name);
        }
    }
```

This is the code from onbindviewholder where i am settingthe tag -

```
 getMyCategoryAdapter1 =  category_name.get(i);

        viewHolder.view.setActivated(selectedList.contains(i));
        viewHolder.view.setTag("items:" + getMyCategoryAdapter1.getC_name());
        viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

I want to give background color to i_name on toggleselected() method.HOw can i do this.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103473/how-to-clear-highlighted-items-in-the-recyclerview/54103578#54103578

Comment: Why did you make the code so complicated??

Comment: @Piyush Are you talking about using xml to change color on item click

Comment: @Piyush..I am new to andriod and couldn't think of a much easier way.can you help?

Comment: @Ranjit no i want to change the background color problematically only, but how do i do that? I am not able to get the view on toggleselected method so that i can change the color of it.

Comment: @Piyush there are easier ways but i have a search feature in my code also where the positions of the items get updated o i cant rely on positions.

Comment: @payal_suthar follow this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692214/changing-background-color-of-selected-item-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

**Basic idea for selecting and disselecting items in a recyclerview.**

Maintain a tag in your model for selected and unselected.

for e.x

```
boolean isSelected;
```

when you populate the data make all values in your list for `isSelected` false bydefault.

Then in your long press set the value of `isSelected` to true for that position only in your arraylist and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

and in your `onbindviewholder` check

```
if(yourModel.isSelected){

// show the row selected

}else {

// show the row unselected

}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Ya but here in my code, i am updating the boolean variable newState on toggle selected but how do i get the view id of the particular string i_name?