# RecyclerView items select and deselect

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have 4 item in RecyclerView how can i make it possible when i select 4th item deselect other option and when select any of other 3 then selected 4th option will be deselected in android RecyclerView

```
 viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(gridItem.isSelectedItem() == false && gridItem.getProblemReason().equals("None of the Above")){
                Glide.with(mContext).load((R.drawable.ic_redcross))
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).skipMemoryCache(true)
                        .into(viewHolder.iv_selection);
                if (gridItem.getKey() != null) {
                    stringArrayList.clear();
                    stringArrayList.add(gridItem.getKey());
                }
                gridItem.setSelectedItem(true);
            }
            else {
                Glide.with(mContext).load(((int) gridItem.getProblemImgSelection()))
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).skipMemoryCache(true)
                        .into(viewHolder.iv_selection);
                if (gridItem.getKey() != null) {
                    stringArrayList.remove(gridItem.getKey());
                }
                gridItem.setSelectedItem(false);
            }
```

Comment: Please post code you have tried.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103578/7666442

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not getting result as i expect!

Answer (score 0):

you need creat arraylist have object selected boolean
when you select item make it inside arraylist true and another item false and notfy changed
if(arrayliast.get(possion)=true){
code
}
else{
code
}

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable in your adapter class,
`int prevPosition = -1;`
In onBindView method,

```
if (prevPosition == position) {
    // set background for selected item 
}
else {
    // set background for not selected item
}
```

On holder click,

```
`prevPosition = position;`
```